# ggplot duplicates identical values on the y-axis that are improperly scaled

Tags: r, ggplot2

Very strange (to me), the code below, dependent on the `accuracy = _` argument radically alters the y-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = prop)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 5))
```

If I vary the `accuracy =` three different ways, eg `accuracy = 5`, `accuracy = 6`, and `accuracy = 10`, I get the three plots shown below. Notice the y-axis is all over the map. In the worst case it plots `40%` twice? When it looks like it should obviously be `50%`.

I've got a suspicion there is a mathematical reason for this I can't see and you can. But what is it? And should there be an R console warning for this type of behavior?

`accuracy = 5`
[image: accuracy5]

`accuracy = 6`
[image: accuracy6]

`accuracy = 10`
[image: accuracy10]

Comment: The accuracy setting takes the individual breaks in the scale, in this case, the default, and then assigns them a label based on rounding the breaks to the nearest 10.  You get a double label, but the actual break value is still the same (else the position of your dot would change).